# Reporting Services: Custom Assembly and subscription

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to get an SSRS report that uses a Custom Assembly for labels in different languages. In the Preview and for a single report everything works fine. But, when the report is generated by the subscription-process, instead of the label there are only '#error'-items. Is there a special user for the subscription-process, who needs some special rights for the assembly?

I hope you can help.

Roman

Comment: This is probably not due to user-rights, more likely something's different between preview and running in as a subscription, such as data, deployment of the custom assembly, parameters, etc. You'll need to debug that and get back to us with more info, as the question stands it's guess work for us, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved the problem:

The assembly need some connection strings. For a single report they have to be in the web.config and for the subscription-process they have to be in the ReportingServicesService.exe.config....